Which water cave in Yangshuo is best?
China's Guilin city, and particularly Yangshuo area have multiple 'water caves' but there's very limited information online.
If any cave enthusiasts have visited- I would like to understand which ones are the best, and if it's worth the time.
I know most caves in China are not 'natural' with neon lightings and commercial shops. But that aside, which are the best caves?

What's "best" for you? Largest, most natural, least crowded, ...?

Just looking to get some personal opinions of others- not an objective definition of best.

In that case, your question will likely be closed because it's opinion based.

Do you have a list of water caves you're considering, and websites / maps locations for them?  I went to one in 2012 (which I would not recommend) but I don't remember what it was called.

"Limited information online" but did you look at Tripadvisor, and their other posts?
